# Add Page Carrousel

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have built a simple and basic app. In order to help people to understand easly the app.

I would like to create a dynamic turorial. My idea is put differents content's pages in a carousel or collection view. And In every content's pages there is an image in background and I will add label and box to explain fonctionalities

Here you will find an example of an image that I will put in background of content page and add label to explain highlighted information

[image]

**My question are :**

I have 3 content pages that I will put backgroud image on it :
home =new HomePage(), Page2 page2 =new Page2() & Page3 page3 =new Page3()

1. how can i easly add label where I want as the image will be in background ?
2. how I can put those content pages in carrousel view or collection view ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create carousel like this:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <CarouselView x:Name="cvTutorial" ItemsSource="{Binding Tutorials}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" PeekAreaInsets="10" IsScrollAnimated="True" PositionChanged="cvTutorial_PositionChanged">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid RowSpacing="0" Padding="0"  HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="tutorialImg" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                                Margin="{DynamicResource 50,40,50,00}" HeightRequest="350"/>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" Padding="0,30,0,0" Spacing="15">
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource RobotoBoldSize24WhiteLabelStyle}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" Padding="10,10,10,0" />
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource RobotoRegularSize16LightGrayLabelStyle}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Subtitle}" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                               Padding="50,10,50,10" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
    <Grid x:Name="indicatorGrid" ColumnSpacing="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="{DynamicResource MarginPadding00_20_00_40}"
          ColumnDefinitions = "25,25,25">
        
        <pancake:PancakeView x:Name="Dot_1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource SelectedIndicatorStyle}" />
        <pancake:PancakeView x:Name="Dot_2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource UnselectedIndicatorStyle}" />
        <pancake:PancakeView x:Name="Dot_3" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource UnselectedIndicatorStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Check working sample - https://rb.gy/mlmh0q

Comment: Can ou please tell my how I can I add  my Content pages in this carousel.  I have something like :  HomePage  home =new HomePage(); &  Page2  page2 =new Page2();

Comment: You don't have to add pages you just have to add content to it. Replace ItemsSource="{Binding Tutorials}" with your data. Its basically a List<Model> items. Just add it and it will work. Check the official document for details - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data

Comment: I would like to add content of my page note only Data

Comment: The pages have diffrent format this is why i am looking for a carousel type of page

Comment: Yes, so you can modify the ui part as well in above code. What I have done is First it will show image, below that first it will show Title text with fontsize 24, after that description text. This is what we have mostly in tutorial pages.

Comment: ok, then you have to create your own custom ui. Because we use carousel when we want to display Some ui with different data with Horizontal scroll. You can change ui also based on bool flags that you have to manage from ViewModel of that page, this is just one idea, there are different possible ways.